# Scaffolding failed. Could not load information for project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Gaving an issue with the add of Scaffoolding item. Getting an error like this..

[this the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9bWm.png)

[this is solution files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5P8d.png)

Any tips ?

Comment: Hi, Same i am getting after just latest update of vscodd 2022, find any solution?

Comment: Not really yet. Thinking of reverting VS version backwards.

Comment: yea me too my all project stoped working. so how to revert ?

Comment: Hi, i have some issues after updated vs 2022

Comment: Maybe try here: https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1388

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/2019 for the issue and a potential work around, it's a bug in the scaffolding.

Comment: @ŠarūnasBrazdžionis Remove all project references in the project you are working on, then you won't get error. After adding Areas etc. you can again add project references

Comment: i just update scaffolding design lib and working fine. but i got lots of update also in VS2022 till now